Why are Contour Integrals defined the way they are?
I have a question about Contour Integrals.
Contour Integrals are defined as $$\int_{C} f(z)dz = \int_{a}^{b} f(z(t))z'(t)dt \tag{1}$$.
But why define it this way?
The textbook I'm using (Complex Variables and Applications by Brown and Churchill) simply gave this definition with little explanation. I read that Contour Integrals have no geometric interpretation and are used instead to help evaluate real-valued definite integrals. But as someone who just finished Calculus 2 and 3 where all the integrals were constructed from Riemann Sums and had a clear geometric meaning, this seems strange to me.
I notice that this definition looks similar to the definition of a line integral from Calculus 3, $$\int_{a}^{b} f(r(t))|r'(t)|dt \tag{2}$$.
But they are not quite the same.
Can anyone please explain that?

Are you asking about the whole term or asking only about why the $|\cdot|$ is missing ?

Well, that is something I just noticed. Even if there is no connection to real-valued line integrals, why do we define the contour integral in this way? It's strange, because I understand the CIF, residues, etc. perfectly well, because they make sense algebraically, but intuitively, I don't understand what contour integration actually IS. The definition seems so random.

The way integration works is that we chop up the object we’re integrating over into tiny pieces, compute the contribution of each piece, then sum up all the individual contributions. Let $C$ be a curve in the complex plane and let $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$. I’m not imagining that $C$ is parametrized. Chop up $C$ into tiny pieces. The end points of the $i$th piece are $z_i$ and $z_{i+1}$. The contribution of the $i$th piece is $f(z_i) (z_{i+1} - z_i)$. The integral $\int_C f , dz$ is the sum of all these little contributions. That is the conceptual meaning of a contour integral.

Now parametrize $C$ and work out the details to discover the contour integral formula that you’ve been given.

You don't say where you found this comment, but writing of any mathematical object that it has "no geometrical interpretation" is rather an admission of one's inability to make one when some better minds will.

Instead of the scalar line integral, I would say that the more closely related concept from vector calculus is the vector line integral: $\int\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int\vec F(\vec r(t))\cdot\vec r'(t)dt$.

How would you interpret the differential $dz$ in the object $\int_C f(z),dz$?

Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110334/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/446724/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904493/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111368/96384.

@Joce: The textbook OP quotes (Brown/Churchill) literally says this in its section on Contour Integrals (sec. 44 p.125 of the 9th edition): "Definite integrals in [real] calculus can be interpreted as areas, and they have other interpretations as well. Except in special cases, no corresponding helpful interpretation, geometric or physical, is available for integrals in the complex plane." [I agree with your comment and just quote this FYI.]

A more natural way to define them is analogous to Riemann sums. Indeed for the usual Riemann integral we would define
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x:=\lim_{\lVert\mathcal{P}\rVert\to0}\sum_{j=1}^nf(x_j^*)(x_j-x_{j-1}),$$
where the limit is taken over all tagged partitions $\mathcal{P}$ of $[a,b]$. Say we instead want to integrate along a curve $\gamma$. Then a very natural way to do this would be to replace the $x_j-x_{j-1}$ with $\gamma(x_j)-\gamma(x_{j-1})$, i.e. the distance between two points on the curve, and to replace $x_j^*$ with $\gamma(x_j^*)$, as we wish to evaluate our function at a point on the curve between the two we just measured the distance of. This leads us to defining
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z:=\lim_{\lVert\mathcal{P}\rVert\to0}\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))(\gamma(x_j)-\gamma(x_{j-1})),$$
where $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is a curve. Let us assume that $\gamma$ is $C^1$. Then we have the expansion
$$\gamma(t)=\gamma(s)+\gamma'(s)(t-s)+R(t-s),$$
where $\frac{R(t-s)}{t-s}\to0$ as $t\to s$. Consequently
$$\gamma(x_j)-\gamma(x_{j-1})=\gamma'(x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j-1})+R(x_j-x_{j-1}).$$
But then notice that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))(\gamma(x_j)-\gamma(x_{j-1}))
&=\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))(\gamma'(x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j-1})+R(x_j-x_{j-1})) \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))\gamma'(x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j-1})+\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))R(x_j-x_{j-1}).
\end{align*}
Notice how the first term in this sum looks an awful lot like a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$, the only difference being that we evaluate $f\circ\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ at different points in the subintervals of the partition. This is where the assumption of $\gamma$ being $C^1$ saves us. I will not go into the details, because my point is to give you the idea of why the definition you've seen makes sense, but one can now show that the second term also vanishes as the mesh of the partition goes to zero, and so one obtains that
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\lim_{\lVert\mathcal{P}\rVert\to0}\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))(\gamma(x_j)-\gamma(x_{j-1}))=\underbrace{\lim_{\lVert\mathcal{P}\rVert\to0}\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))\gamma'(x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j-1})}_{=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}+\underbrace{\lim_{\lVert\mathcal{P}\rVert\to0}\sum_{j=1}^nf(\gamma(x_j^*))R(x_j-x_{j-1})}_{=0}=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,$$
and so you can see that, with this much more natural definition, analogous to what we do on the real line, we obtain the formula you have for sufficiently nice functions.

Shouldn't $\gamma$ take values in $\mathbb{C}$?

@Joce indeed, that was a typo, thanks!

The (smooth directed) contour is parameterised by $z=\gamma(t)$ where $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$. Then the contour integral definition can be intuitively thought of as a simple case of substitution, where the differential term $dz=\gamma'(t)dt$. Which gives you your $$\int_Cf(z)dz=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$
I'm glossing over some rigorosities, since it seems like you're more interested in the intuition.

Complex integration is completely analogous to the real-valued Riemann integral you're familiar with, in the sense that you partition the curve into elements, sum up the weighted function values, then take the limit as the elements become infinitesimally small. The difference is in the real-valued case, the "weights" are the lengths of the $\Delta x$ elements, but in the complex case the "weights" are the small complex numbers $\Delta z$.
This is probably why you read that there is no "geometric intepretation", because while $f(x)\Delta x$ are rectangles in the real-valued sum, there is no nice geometric representation of the complex-valued $f(z)\Delta z$.

Complex integrals are certainly similar to line integrals, which are$$\int_C f(\mathbf{r}) ds$$
Informally, $ds$ is the length of an infinitesmial element of the arc, which can be substituted for $$ds=|\mathbf{r}'(t)|dt$$given some parameterisation $\mathbf{r}(t)$.
The difference (again, informally) is the line integral integrates over infinitesimal real lengths $ds$, but the complex integral is over infinitesimal complex numbers $dz$.

Good answer, +1. But if one tries harder, one can find "geometric interpretations" of those complex valued little product increments $f(z)\Delta z$, just (of course) not as rectangles. See e.g. the answers by Steven Gubkin, and tryst with freedom, to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110334/96384.

Line Integral :
Let us say we have a Curve $\gamma$ from $a$ to $b$ like this :

Along the Curve $\gamma$ , we have some number we want to integrate. Eg We put some tar on the curvy road. At Point $r$ , we use $f(r)$ amount of tar where $ds$ is the road strip size. We want total tar used.
Naturally , we want to integrate over all such Points $r$ on Curve $\gamma$ :
$$\int_\gamma f(r) ds = \int_a^b f(r) ds$$
We do not know how to do that easily , we do know Definite Integration. Hence we want to put it on a linear line such that at Point $t$ , we get the Point on the Curve $r(t)$ & then Integrate over $t$. It is just the usual change of variables , nothing more to it. It introduces the term $r'(t)dt$ in place of $ds$
$$\int_a^b f(r(t)) r'(t)dt$$
It will look some thing like this :

We can also see that when curve moves forwards , eg at $t_1$ , $r'(t)$ is Positive , while when curve moves backwards , eg at $t_2$ , $r'(t)$ is Negative : It will make the Integral add the tar amount & subtract the tar amount depending on the Sign. We do not want that : We always want to add. Hence , we introduce "absolute value" to eliminate Negative values.
$$\int_\gamma f(r) ds = \int_a^b f(r(t)) |r'(t)|dt$$
Contour Integral :
Situation is same , except that the value we want to integrate over are all Complex numbers. There is no Concept of Positive or Negative now.
At Point $z$ on the Curve $\gamma$ having tiny strip $dz$ , we have some number $f(z)$.
$$\int_\gamma f(r) dz = \int_a^b f(z) dz$$
We do not know how to get that , hence we introduce Parameter $t$ to convert to linear line.
Point $t$ with the usual change or variables is on the linear line , which corresponds to the tiny strip $z'(t)dt$ at the Point $z(t)$ on the Curve.
$$\int_\gamma f(r) dz = \int_a^b f(z(t)) z'(t)dt$$
It will look like the Definite Integral given earlier , except that the function will have Complex values.
Here , we general want to add & subtract (Eg Current or force or magnetism) the values , hence we do not use $|z'(t)|$.
SUMMARY :
In Line Integral , $r$ moves along the curvy line.
With Change of variables , $t$ moves from real number $0$ to $1$ to match $a$ & $r$ & $b$ on the Curve.
In Contour Integral , $z$ moves along the curvy Contour.
With Change of variables , $t$ moves from real number $0$ to $1$ to match $a$ & $z$ & $b$ on the Contour.
