# Including the derivative length in line integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to find the following line integral:

$\int_{C} y^{3} d s, \quad C: x=t^{3}, \quad y=t, 0 \leqslant t \leq 2 $

In class I was given the following formula

$$
\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{s}=\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{F}(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma^{\prime}(t) d t
$$
and
$$
\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{s}=\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F}(\gamma(t)) \cdot \mathbf{T}(t) d s
$$

Which one would I apply to solve this problem?

---

I thought I would solve it this way

$\gamma(t)=(t^3,t)$ and $\gamma'(t)=(3t^2,1)$ Then

$\int_C(0,y^3)ds=\int_0^2 (0,t^3)\cdot (3t^2,1)dt =\int_0^2 t^3 dt$

However, the book and online soures say this is wrong.

---

An online resource says to do it this way. Why does what I wrote not follow from the definition given in class?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, the question is to integrate a density over the arclength (scalar line integral). The formula you quoted originally is for integrating a vector's dot product over the curve (vector line integral).

Comment: More details: If you have thread with mass density then finding the mass density corresponds to F cdot ds over the thread. But, if you are in a river being pushed by force and want to know the work, then you'd have to dot product the river's push with on the curve you travel over a path to find the energy you've gained.

Comment: What do you mean by a "density" is this at every point of the curve, there is a function at this point?

Comment: Would a complex contour integal be viewed as integrating a dot product or integrating a density?

Comment: Good question! I've written an answer on exactly this elsewhere. Let me find it for you

Comment: [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4405266/688539)

Comment: Thank you per question 1, so I should view F as a mapping from the space containing the arc to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134956/discussion-between-buraian-and-sam-kirkiles).