# Solving contour integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

When evaluating the integral of real functions like
$\int_0^\infty f(x)\cos(ax)dx$
where $a$ is a real constant, why can't I simply do contour integration by using the complex function $f(z)\cos(az)$?
An example would be most helpful. Thank you.

Comment: A half line is not a closed line. You can do contour integration on contours.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So, if I try to solve it as 1/2∫-∞∞()() it should work

Comment: No it is not what I mean. Learn about holomorphic functions and contour integrals first.

Comment: Another passionate highschooler? :) The idea in your question is not clear. I remember when I was at this stage long back. I suggest you check out the book Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis, it's very accessible book. You can check my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110334/line-integration-in-complex-analysis/4405266#4405266) for some quick info. I am not sure you will understand much but keep at it!